# port name showing up as gibberish

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm running arduino 1.6.6 sketchbook, and been using the sketch book for my arduino uno for a couple of months. A week ago roughly it started acting weird, for a reason I haven't been able to figure out even after extensive googling.
I got Windows 10 educational version (free version thx to my uni).
[image: The serial port name is gibberish]

In device manager, the board shows up correctly (named itself COM3 Arduino Uno)
[image: Device manager, shows up correctly]

I suspect it might have to do with drivers somehow, but reinstalls, updates, and every option I have tried so far has failed. The error that the sketchbook gives is avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM3?ðÕ&¬ôÕ&´æiúd??þÿÿÿÈð": The system cannot find the file specified.

Has anyone seen something similar before?

Comment: Can you bring up command line and run `arduino.exe --port COM3` (you may have to first cd to the path where arduino is installed). See [arduino manpage](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc) Just curious, did it stop working after the Tuesday update?

Comment: just did that, the load-in page for arduino runs for about 1 sec, and then the process kill itself.
About that update, it might be related, although haven't paid attention to updates so can't say for sure.

Comment: yes, as it should, but then when you re-launch the arduino IDE, it should remember the port setting as COM3. The menu will probably still be messed up, but the status bar should at least have the right port selected.

Comment: Correct, but doesn't solve my issue, as the status bar had the correct port selected already from before.

Comment: Ah well, that's why I didn't post this as an answer... I don't have a win10 system to test on. I thought maybe Arduino IDE was sending wrong port name to avrdude, but the --port setting should have fixed that.

Comment: Just noticed you're using Arduino 1.6.6 which was released only a couple weeks ago, can you try using the stable version 1.6.5 instead? Maybe this is a regression bug.

Comment: It looks like a badly terminated string in C - except it's java. Maybe you need a new version of Java installed?

Comment: I just tried installing the version 1.6.5, and downloaded&installed the latest version of Java, and restarted the computer. Didn't work though. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Problem was caused by the jdk, updating that solved it. Majenko's comment was helpful. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this problem is persistent. Same problem came back, and updating the jdk again doesn't fix it again. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try updating the IDE or restarting the computer.